# Issues running FSL command in Linux environment

Tags: linux, matlab

I am new to FSL, using version 4.1.8. I am trying to run a script that reads and generates `*.nii` files, which format is normally supported by FSL. I am calling an FSL function, `probtrackx` from within `Matlab`. However, I get the following error message seemingly unable to generate or recognize `*.nii` files:

```
** ERROR (nifti_image_read): failed to find header file for '~/Documents/fMRI_data/../DTI/fsl_dti/masks/target_mask_001'

** ERROR: nifti_image_open(~/Documents/fMRI_data/../DTI/fsl_dti/masks/target_mask_001): bad header info

ERROR: failed to open file ~/Documents/fMRI_data/../DTI/fsl_dti/masks/target_mask_001

ERROR: Could not open image ~/Documents/fMRI_data/../DTI/fsl_dti/masks/target_mask_001
```

The files do exist but FSL fails to recognize them. Any help as to how to correct the issue and get FSL to work properly would be most appreciated. I suspect it's a Linux settings issue, just not sure how to fix it. A solution to a related problem in a previous posting suggested adding `ls='ls --color=auto'`. I've tried it to on avail.

Answer (score 0):

Some FSL tools assume that the `$FSLDIR` unix unvironment variable is set, which might not be the case in your MATLAB environment. You can fix that with something like `setenv('FSLDIR', '/usr/local/fsl')` (modified of course if your FSL installation is in a different place). Some also need the regular FSL setup script to be executed as well: `system('. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh')`. See also: http://www.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fsl/downloading.html.

Instead of the more complicated `probtrackx` script, another thing to try first is simply:

```
system('fslhd ~/Documents/fMRI_data/../DTI/fsl_dti/masks/target_mask_001')
```

If this fails with the same error, then you know that you entered the path to the data incorrectly. For example, do you mean to have the `..` in there?

Also, in the future, the best place to get FSL support is on their mailing list at: https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A0=fsl

Comment: Thanks for commenting and suggesting solutions. setenv('FSLDIR', '/usr/local/fsl') is already in the env, and I also tried system('. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh') to no avail. Interestingly, the same script seems to work fine on my colleague's computer.

Thanks for suggesting system('fslhd ~/Documents/fMRI_data/../DTI/fsl_dti/masks/target_mask_001'), 
it worked fine, which I assume suggests that the files are not corrupted. I will try the script on a different computer.

Happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Does MATLAB have access to run other fsl commands? If you are able to run a command from the command line but not through MATLAB, the MATLAB user may not have access to run fsl or may be looking for some FSL variables.

You might have to do the [equivalent of this](http://ftp.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/pub/dist/freesurfer/tutorial_packages/OSX/fsl_501/doc/fsl/macosx.html#matlab) for a linux system

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).